# required in html5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, html

i need to write a javascript or a jquery function to similar the required validation in html5 to display validation-bubble-message but i don't want to use the required tag because i'm using custom validators on buttons

any suggestions?

note that i'm asp.net with vb

```
 <p> 
      <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your username </label>
                                <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="myusername"/>
</p>
<p> 
   <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
     <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate(form) {
                var valid = true;
                $(form).children().filter('input[validate=required]').each(
                        function() {
                            if (this.value == '') {                                
                                alert("A value for " + this.getAttribute('title') + " is required");
                                valid = false;
                            }
                        }
                );
                return valid;
            }
        </script>

    </head>    
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" 
                         id="username" 
                         name="username"                 
                         placeholder="myusername"
                         validate="required"
                         title="Username"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

"validate" is a made up attribute, you can use anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using http://jqueryvalidation.org/

particularly look at the example given at http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

This doesn't give you nice "bubbles" out of the box, but a clear error message below the input field, and may be useful for you - or at least a good starting point.
The demo shows that apparently this doesn't interfere with existing html5 capabilities of the browser. Also, the author explains why he thinks it's not such a great idea to implement this kind of validation on your own, although the implementations shown here in other answers may be perfectly working for you.

As I'm not familiar with ASP, I don't know whether it takes care of "automatic" server-side validation in this case (maybe not). So if ever the user manages to get the form submitted with empty fields (not hard, maybe using a GET URL, or manipulating the page before submit), your server-side code should be able to deal with that and, for example, redirect the user to the form again, ideally also showing an appropriate error message.